# undefined method `type' for #<Order id: nil, paper_size: "A4", color: "Black & White", quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

i am getting this error whenever i try to save data from the form into database using the submit button, can someone please explain me why this is happening and whats the reason?
i am new to RoR and still learning :')

```
undefined method `type' for #<Order id: nil, paper_size: "A4", color: "Black & White", quantity: 16, paper_style: "Black to Back", description: "asdasdasdasd", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: "test", last_name: "example", phone_number: 123456789, email: "example@test.com">
```

> orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    # GET to /orders/new
    def new
        @order = Order.new
    end

    # POST to /orders
    def create
        @order = Order.create(order_params)
        if @order.save
            redirect_to root_path
            
        else
            redirect_to about_path
        end
    end

    private
        def order_params
            params.require(:order).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :email, :paper_size, :color, :paper_style, :quantity, :description, files: [] )
        end
end
```

> views/orders/new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Order From Home!</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

            <%= form_for @order do |f| %>          
                <%= f.label :first_name%>
                <%= f.text_field :first_name, class:"form-control" %><br/>

                <%= f.label :last_name %>
                <%= f.text_field :last_name, class:"form-control" %><br/>
            

                <%= f.label :phone_number %>
                <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class:"form-control" %><br/>

            
                <%= f.label :email %>
                <%= f.text_field :email, class:"form-control" %><br/>

                <%= f.label :files %>
                <%= f.file_field :files, multiple: true %><br/>
            

                <%= f.label :paper_size %>
                <%= f.select :paper_size, ['A4', 'B4'], { prompt: 'Select' }, class:'form-select' %><br/>

                <%= f.label :color %>
                <%= f.select :color, ['Black & White', 'Color'], { prompt: 'Select' }, class:'form-select' %><br/>

                <%= f.label :paper_style %>
                <%= f.select :paper_style, ['Black to Back', 'Side to Side'], { prompt: 'Select' }, class:'form-select' %><br/>

                <%= f.label :quantity %>
                <%= f.select :quantity, options_for_select(0..500), { prompt: "Select" }, class:'form-select' %><br/>

                <%= f.label :description %>
                <%= f.text_area :description, class:"form-control" %><br/>

                <div class="btn-order">
                    <%= f.submit %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

> schema.rb (orders table)

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "paper_size"
    t.string "color"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.string "paper_style"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.integer "phone_number"
    t.string "email"
  end
```

why is this happening and whats the differnece between @order.create and @order.new??

**UPDATE**
my order.rb ( model ) had validations for `:type`, from what i have heard from people saying is that we should avoid using `type` and `date` while creating a table in rails

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    
    belongs_to :admin

    validates :paper_size, presence: true
    validates :color, presence: true
    validates :quantity, presence: true
    validates :type, presence: true
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :phone_number, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true

   

    has_many_attached :files
end
```

i changed the column name in db table through migrations and replaced the new column name in model file to this

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    
    belongs_to :admin

    validates :paper_size, presence: true
    validates :color, presence: true
    validates :quantity, presence: true
    validates :paper_style, presence: true
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :phone_number, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true

   

    has_many_attached :files
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def new 
    @order = Order.new -> It will create new Order Object
end
```

Once Form complete Create action will be called

```
def create 
@order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save 
       # Print success msg
    else
       @order.errors
    end
end
```

`Order.create` will directly create an object with params passed to into instead of assigning. Also `Order.create!(order_params)` will raise error if any errors in it.

You can find your errors using Order.create!(order_params) in your console.

> Solution

:
**Remove the validation names "type" in order.rb**

[image]

Comment: @uma, 
From the Ref- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447951/strong-parameters-not-being-saved-in-the-database-rails-7

I found the issue with your model. Please remove 
    validates :type, presence: true  --- order.rb  (because you don't have column name "type".

Comment: I'd recommend that you [not post a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008) but instead post the actual text in a code block for improved searchability and reliability.

Comment: oh yes i have that validates :type in my model file, i forgot to check it, thanks for the info!